# How to add font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums; to jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying to apply font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums to this and it won't work also I don't know if it's supposed to work 
Check out for more info
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-numeric
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjAfnc7UmM4&t=214s

```
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();
var x = setInterval(function() {
var now = new Date().getTime();
var distance = countDownDate - now;
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 
60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 
60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h 
"
+ minutes + "m " + seconds + "s " + "till release on Jan 5, 2021";
if (distance < 0) {
clearInterval(x);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
}
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`.css( propertyName, value )`](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css2) API to add CSS properties to a HTML element.

```
$("#demo").css("font-variant-numeric": "tabular-nums")
```

**Suggestion**: I would recommend defining a new class in a `stylesheet` (e.g. `foo.css`) and use jQuery's [`.addClass( className )`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) API to style your HTML element.